# Why are database queries a good place to use Arrows?

Tags: haskell, arrows, opaleye

I was reading [this](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-21-arrows.html), which said:

> Well, the point is that arrow notation forbids some computations that do notation allows. In particular all “arrow actions” must be “statically” known“.

and it explains:

> Statically known" means that if we have a couple of rows of arrow notation
>
> `> --    y <- action1 -< x`
>
> `> --    z <- action2 -< y`
>
> then the expression action2 cannot depend on x or indeed anything bound on the left hand side of an arrow notation row.

As far as I understand, this restriction is what makes arrows worthwhile.

Now, I was trying to learn Opaleye and I noticed that it uses arrows to combine things together.

Why is Opaleye using arrows? Why are arrows a well suited thing for this job? What is it about databases/queries that make this restriction useful?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the idea that that "restriction" is what makes arrows worthwhile. It's pretty trivial to get around using arrow apply, and there's even nice syntactic sugar to do that: `z <- action2 x -<< y`

Comment: Also, this might be helpful reading if you haven't seen it yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652054/monads-vs-arrows?rq=1

Comment: I think it's fundamentally missing the point to always compare arrows to monads. Arrows are foremostly a generalisation of functions/morphisms, whereas monads layer upon objects. Of course, both concepts are strongly linked in a cartesian closed category, but it's still a quite different conceptual approach.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's fair. I think because they can both capture effectful actions, there is general confusion on when each is more appropriate of a solution so they get compared to each other a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Paramaterized database queries look like arrows:

- each has an input and an output
- they compose
- we want to treat them differently than Haskell functions

Composition `(.)` (or `(<<<)`) looks like an SQL subquery.  `(&&&)` looks like an SQL join.

I believe that the "statically known" restriction relates to things you might reasonably be able to translate into SQL.  Once you allow `fmap` / `lmap` / `rmap` with arbitrary Haskell functions, that isn't feasible (at least without SQL language extensions and GHC compiler plugins).  I haven't worked out the details, though.

I don't know how many of the translations we might manage by hand Opaleye implements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difficulty around variable scope when combining aggregation and monadic bind in query languages.  I've never come up with a particularly satisfying explanation but you can see [a historical Reddit post of mine](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2nxx7n/announcing_opaleye_sqlgenerating_embedded_domain/cmhyr17/) and a [(fixed) issue with relational-record](https://github.com/khibino/haskell-relational-record/issues/19) for some details.